# How to make sure requested image resolution will not throw out of memory exception

Tags: java, pdf, memory, adobe, heap-memory

Is there a way to ensure calling a function to get an image will not be too much to fit in available memory?

```
int[] intBuf = util.getAbgrRect(page, x, y, w, h, wPix, hPix);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically any kind of guessing method is going to be unreliable. You could make sure that you've got plenty of memory available on your system, and set some large enough hard limits that you declare shouldn't be exceeded.

If all else fails, you can always do the unthinkable and write

```
int[] intBuf = null;
try {
    intBuf = util.getAbgrRect(page, x, y, w, h, wPix, hPix);
} catch(OutOfMemoryError e) {
    // abort processing
}
```

It's not pretty, but it'll work. Just be careful.